# jQuery.change() not compatible with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this problem when using plain Javascript mixed with jQuery(two different libraries I am using). So for a text input field, the plain Javascript library rely on the change event binding added using addEventListener method. The other jQuery Plugin(datetimepicker) is used to change the field and a jQuery.change() method is triggered after the value is updated.

The problem is, the listener is not triggered by the jQuery event.
Here is some simple code to illustrate the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="abc">abc abc.</input>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener("change", function(){
  alert('change event triggered');
 });
$('#abc').change();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Given the very simple html page like this, the event listener actually will not be triggered by the jQuery.change() method, so the alert box will not be displayed. If I change the input field manually, the event works fine.

Follow up:
If use jQuery for event binding and triggering, there is no problem.
The problem is, I am using one library that is written in plain Javascript(JSONEditor[https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor]), and the event binding is added using the Javascript API, and other libraries I am using changed some input field and triggered the event with jQuery, and the event is not captured.

Comment: javascript isn't a library. jQuery is a javascript library.

Comment: why can't you use jQuery event handlers

Comment: this code works fine without jquery. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qw2z22m9/

Comment: I am using two different Libraries, one is written in plain javascript without dependencies, other is written jQuery syntax. They do not interact via change event well.

Comment: Thanks, @Aditya, the event listener will capture the event when I change the field manually, but jQuery triggered event is not captured though, that is my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `jQuery.change()` (and `jQuery.trigger()`) does not trigger listeners added with `addEventListener`.

This is currently a WONTFIX for jQuery (see closed issues [#2476](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2476), [#3347](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3347)) ([source](https://makandracards.com/makandra/71890-events-triggered-by-jquery-cannot-be-observed-by-native-event-listeners))

My workaround:

Replace

```
$('#abc').change(); // or $('#abc').trigger('change');
```

with this:

```
$('#abc')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

First you pull out the native DOM element from jQuery element (`$('#abc'][0] ([source](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/))) and then dispatch your event. This way dispatched event will be handled by native and jQuery listeners. See [demo](https://codepen.io/raigu/pen/VwaJbzQ).

Answer (score 1):

use **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** in jquery

```
$('#abc').on("change", function(){
    alert('change event triggered');
}).trigger("change");
```

Comment: I just like to understand why jQuery triggered event cannot be captured by the listener. There are definitely some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping jquery code inside `document.ready()` and use simple jquery event handler for this purpose as shown :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#abc').on('change',function(){
    alert("here");
  }).change(); // trigger `.change()` event on page load.
});
</script>
```

Or if you are generating HTML dynamically with Jquery,then try **event delegation** :-

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('change','#abc',function(){
        alert("here");
    }).change(); // trigger `.change()` event on page load.
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not easily use jquery event handler as the event binding is added by JSONEditor([https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor])

Comment: Sorry,I think I failed to make the question very clear. The question is how to trigger a listener added by method addEventListener in jQuery.